# How to get the last part of a string in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string in C that contains a file path like "home/usr/wow/muchprogram".

I was wondering in C how I can get the string after the last "/". So Then I could store it as a variable. That variable would equal "muchprogram" to be clear.

I am also wondering how I could get everything before that final "/" as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: strrchr would help you get the last part after /

Comment: You can split the string by the / using the split method: And then access the result. Here is how to do it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: You could also use regex.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy That's a great function. Is there an equivalent one for getting everything before the last char?

Comment: @Twisterz Collect your complete string in a temporary pointer. Put a NULL where you find the last "/". You then get the string before the final "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start scanning the string from the end. Once you get a `/` stop. Note the `index` and copy from `index+1` to `last_index`, to a new array.

You get everything before the final `/` as well. You have the `index`. Start copying from `start_index` to `index-1`, to a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else already suggested this, but they forgot to include the C. This assumes it is ok to mutate the source string. Tested with GCC 4.7.3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* s = "home/usr/wow/muchprogram";
  int n = strlen(s);
  char* suffix = s + n;

  printf("%s\n%s\n", s, suffix);

  while (0 < n && s[--n] != '/');
  if (s[n] == '/') {
    suffix = s + n + 1;
    s[n] = '\0';
  }

  printf("%s\n%s\n", s, suffix);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search backwards from the end of the string until you find a `'/'`. The pointer to the next index from there is the string of everything after that. If you copy everything up to, but not including, the `'/'` into another string (or replace the `'/'` with `'\0'`), you obtain the string of everything before the last `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strrchr.html

`strrchr(3)` has been there since C89 for that purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void find_destructive(char *s) {
    char *p_sl = strrchr(s, '/');
    if (p_sl) {
        *p_sl = '\0';
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", s, p_sl + 1);
    } else {
        printf("Cannot find any slashes.\n");
    }
}

static void find_transparent(const char *s) {
    const char *p_sl = strrchr(s, '/');
    if (p_sl) {
        char *first = (char *)malloc(p_sl - s + 1);
        if ( ! first) {
            perror("malloc for a temp buffer: ");
            return;
        }
        memcpy(first, s, p_sl - s);
        first[p_sl - s] = '\0';
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", first, p_sl + 1);
        free(first);
    } else {
        printf("Cannot find any slashes.\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "home/usr/wow/muchprogram";

    find_transparent(s);
    find_destructive(s);

    return 0;
}
```

- http://ideone.com/vApvqp

Comment: Since your functions are only printing, and not returning, the results, you can replace the entire then-branch of `if (p_sl)` in `find_transparent` with: `printf("[%.*s] [%s]\n", (int)(p_sl - s), s, p_sl + 1);` This gets rid of `malloc`, `memcpy`, etc.

Comment: @Arkku You're right.  But I thought the OP's intention was to get two zero-terminated C strings which can be used in any ways.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this in c# as follows..

```
Var tokens = Str.Split('/');
Var lastItem = tokens[tokens.Length-1];
Var everythingBeforeLastItem = string.Empty;
Enumerate.Range(0,tokens.Length-3).ToList().
ForEach(i => everythingBeforeLastItem = everythingBeforeLastItem+tokens[i]+"\");
EverythingBeforeLastItem += tokens[tokens.Length-2];
```

You can use StringBuilder for efficiency if you expect a deeper path resulting in large number of tokens..